# Empty DataGridView after import numbers

Tags: c#, winforms

```cs
namespace WinFormsApp4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                ofd.Filter = "Excel Files only | *.xlsx; *.xls; *.csv;" ;
                ofd.Title = "Choose the file";
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    label1.Text = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void Import_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlapp;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlworkbook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlworksheet;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlrange;
            try
            {
                xlapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                xlworkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(label1.Text);
                xlworksheet = xlworkbook.Worksheets["List1"];
                xlrange = xlworksheet.UsedRange;

                DataMore.ColumnCount = xlrange.Columns.Count;
    
                DataMore.ColumnCount = 6;
                DataMore.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Datum";
                DataMore.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Energia";
                DataMore.Columns[2].HeaderText = "AC výkon";
                DataMore.Columns[3].HeaderText = "napetie siete";
                DataMore.Columns[4].HeaderText = "AC prud";
                DataMore.Columns[5].HeaderText = "DC napetie";

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataMore.Rows)
                {
             
                }
                // for (int xlrow = 1; xlrow <= xlrange.Rows.Count; xlrow++)
                // {
                //   DataMore.Rows.Add(xlrange.Cells[xlrow, 1].Text, xlrange.Cells[xlrow, 2].Text, xlrange.Cells[xlrow, 3].Text,
                //     xlrange.Cells[xlrow, 4].Text);
                // }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hi, first of all im totally beginner in C# programing.
I try import numbers from excel into datagridview. All numbers are in 1 Columns and looks like this:

1,2,3,4,5,
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
16,17,18,19,20

All numbers are not real because original excel has numbers that he collect 24/7 past 5 years and its tons of numbers so i create own small excel...

Im just trying to create program where i import numbers from excel, then i delete Number "0" and then trying to create graphs... But im stuck at start, can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to import Excel data to a `DataGridView` control and say there is a problem where your view stays blank. Looking at your code, I also notice that some of your Excel objects are not being disposed properly, which can lead to multiple instances of Excel running (look in Task Manager).

So, I would like to start from the beginning and look at how to go about this properly in four steps.

[image: excel-to-winforms]

---

**Record class**

Make a class named Record to represent a row of data.

```
class Record
{
    [DisplayName("Datum")]
    public DateTime Datum { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Energia")]
    public double Energia { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("AC výkon")]
    public double ACvýkon { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("napetie siete")]
    public double napetiesiete { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("AC prud")]
    public double ACprud { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("DC napetie")]
    public double DCnapetie { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Auto-configure DataGridView**

Make a `BindingList<Record>` and attach it to the `DataSource` property of the data grid view.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    BindingList<Record> Records { get; } = new BindingList<Record>();

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        dataGridView.DataSource = Records;

        #region F O R M A T    C O L U M N S
        Records.Add(new Record()); // <- Auto-generate columns
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView.Columns)
        {
            column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            if (column.Index > 1) column.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "F2";
        }
        Records.Clear();
        #endregion F O R M A T    C O L U M N S          
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

---

**Configure Excel Interop create and dispose**

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // Create
    _xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    // When in the future the main form closes, dispose the Excel interop.
    Disposed += (sender, e) =>
    {
        _xlBook?.Close();
        _xlApp.Quit();
    }; 
    buttonImport.Click += Import_Click_1;
}
private readonly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application _xlApp;
private Workbook _xlBook = null;
```

---

**Import Data (in this case from a predetermined file location)**

The pieces come together here. Because of the data source binding of `Records` when you add to that collection it displays in the data grid view without having to deal with the control itself.

So after opening the workbook and sheet in Excel, capture the range of all used cells and parse that information to make `Record` instances and add them to the `Records` collection.

```
private void Import_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Records.Clear();
    string filePath = Path.Combine(
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        "Excel",
        "testdata.xlsx");

    _xlBook = _xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
    Worksheet 
        xlSheet = _xlBook.Sheets[1];
    Range 
        xlRange = xlSheet.UsedRange,
        range;
    List<string> 
        headers = new List<string>(),
        line = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= xlRange.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i.Equals(1))
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= xlRange.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                range = xlRange.Cells[i, j];
                headers.Add(range.Value2);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var record = new Record();
            for (int j = 1; j <= xlRange.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                range = xlRange.Cells[i, j];
                var name = headers[j - 1];
                switch(name)
                {
                    case "Datum": record.Datum = DateTime.FromOADate(range.Value2); break;
                    case "Energia": record.Energia = range.Value2; break;
                    case "AC výkon": record.ACvýkon = range.Value2; break;
                    case "napetie siete": record.napetiesiete = range.Value2; break;
                    case "AC prud": record.ACprud = range.Value2; break;
                    case "DC napetie": record.DCnapetie = range.Value2; break;
                    default:
                        Debug.Assert(false, $"Not recognized: '{name}'");
                        break;
                }
            }
            Records.Add(record);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ERROR CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Sheets' and no accessible extension method 'Sheets' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is the error what i got, and i totally dont understand why.

Comment: Im just totally lost here, i was trying just copy your code but i got more and more errors. when i tried create new program with just your code, still a lot errors...the problem is i totally dont understand how to code but my school require it to succesfully end it (after 3 years here we still dont study programing but they require it )

Comment: I'm glad you told me! Do you have Visual Studio 2019? Or 2022? You can open it, say "Clone a repository" in the start menu, and give it this: [copy this link address](https://github.com/IVSoftware/excel-interop-import-numbers-to-datagridview.git). Let's get it working first, then go from there in terms of understanding it.

Comment: EDIT: after instaling .Net framework, the program work but i see some problems... i need button where i can pick excel from my desktop (not already defined) so the user will just kick on button, window will open and they choose file, and second problem is that your excel data are in separate collumns... here is link how that excel looks: https://ibb.co/kqb7sRd
First row (1) (describe what number position means), second row (2) dont know and from third - all the way down are data numbers

Comment: I looked at the image. The data is separated by commas and appears to be `.csv` format. What is the extension of the file?

Comment: As far as `OpenFileDialog` your original post looked like it had functional code for that so just add that code back in now. For this site, we do have to stick to one topic per thread. The topic here is importing numbers using the Excel Interop. You should feel free to post _other_ questions, and you'll get the best answers if you make them very narrow and focused. I suggest you try to keep improving your code and when you get stuck make a new thread for the next thing you get stuck on.

Comment: So i finally put it together with my code but after i click Import button, Datagridview only show 0... in ma previous message i set link, how my excel look like... all numbers are in A and beetwen numbers are ",". Here is second screenshot: https://ibb.co/1vQTMqg.
Datas are in .cvs format because these datas are from fotovoltaic system that work 24/7... they collect data every 5 min and this is how it looks like in summer: https://ibb.co/dmVTynT

Comment: Thx! And yes, I am _very_ familiar with .csv files for data logging :) But here's the thing: reading `.csv` data into a data grid view doesn't require Excel interop at all. There are existing answers but if they don't help you, post a new question named: **Deserialize rows in CSV Data File to bound class for DataGridView** and I'll respond there.